# How to select the column values of sparkR data frame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I created a sparkR dataframe, people

```
+----+-------+
| age|   name|
+----+-------+
|20.0|Michael|
|30.0|   Andy|
|19.0| Justin|
+----+-------+
```

How can i select first value in column "age". In R language we can do by `people$age[1]`, which gives the result 20.0. How can we do the same in sparkR Data frames.

TIA,
Arun

Answer (score 4):

In SparkR you have the function first, which only works on DataFrames, not on columns. Hence you could do

```
first(people)$age
```

This only works for the first item. A SparkR DataFrame has no row indexes, you could however use head or take to decide how many items you want to obtain:

```
head(people, 5)$age
take(people, 5)$age
```

But there is no way to only take the fifth element.

Comment: and what if i wanted [1:2] in dataframe in sparkr